# Is it possible to develop a technology like Google Courgette for iOS?

Tags: ios

It seems that iOS app upgrading requires users to click the "Upgrade" button in App Store.

What if updates are fairly regular and we want automatic upgrading?

I learned that Google Courgette makes it efficient for Chrome browser to upgrade itself fairly frequently.  Each update is created by making a diff from the assembly code of a new version and that of an in-use version. A browser disassemble itself, patches the update and rebuilds itself from the patched assembly code.  This technology is efficient because patches are usually small.

Is it possible for iOS apps to rebuild themselves from some kind of code similar to assembly code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Apple does not allow it, wants to review all updates before releasing them.
It is technically not possible since the application bundle on iOS is readonly.

Comment: Is it possible for an iOS app to store the patch or assembly code as data, and runs it as an interpreted program?  Anyway, program is kind of data.

Comment: No, since your app binary in is in the Application bundle which is readonly. It might be possible on a jailbroke device but never on a standard iOS device. Also Apple will not allow you to do this.

Comment: I mean the data that an iOS app stores locally on the iPhone or iPad. Is such kind of data readonly?

Comment: You can write data to for example the document directory. But you cannot update any data in the apps bunbdle since it is read only. Also Apple does not allow you to run binaries except for the in de app bundle.

Comment: I guess that would be enough for us to make our app self-upgradable.  What I mean is to make the app itself a Lisp (or Python) interpreter and provides iOS APIs for the interpreted Lisp/Python program.  The Lisp/Python programs can be downloaded and saved to the document directory, and executed by the interpreter.  We can upgrade Lisp/Python programs by sending only the diffs between versions.  What do you think?

Comment: I don't think Apple will allow it, since there AppStore review guidelines does not allow this: `2.7 Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected` and `2.8 Apps that install or launch other executable code will be rejected`

Comment: I see. Apple completely banned this idea. Thanks!